# Use function from the main.js in imported module

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to include [`IOUtil.js`](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/tree/master/src/chrome/content/code) and [`ChannelReplacement.js`](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/tree/master/src/chrome/content/code) in my add-on, using the `Cu.import(...)` function. These two both use `xpcom_generateQI`, which I'm trying to obtain from the XPCOM jsm, but the two scripts cant access it.

```
const {Cc, Ci, Cu, Cr} = require("chrome");

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
const xpcom_generateQI = XPCOMUtils.generateQI;
Cu.import(self.data.url("IOUtil.js"));
Cu.import(self.data.url("ChannelReplacement.js"));
```

gives me `xpcom_generateQI is not defined`.
How do I access a function which is defined in main.js?

Comment: this seems so basic, that it leaves me pretty frustrated not being able to get this right for days..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issues

1. Don't use `Cu.import` for local SDK modules. Don't write JS code modules for SDK add-ons, the SDK uses [CommonJS-style modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Module_structure_of_the_SDK) together with the `require()` facility which also comes with proper cleanup for free, which cannot be said for JS code modules and `Cu.import` (you'd need to properly `Cu.unload` everything and likely kill some references yourself).
2. That https-everywhere stuff are neither JS code modules nor SDK modules, but uses the subscript loader. Either convert it to SDK code modules, or use the subscript loader yourself.
3. It is OK to import built-in JS Code modules in different scopes/modules. There is not actually a need to make available `xpcom_generateQI` from main (although it can be done; well, get to that).
4. To be future proof, you should bind your `xpcom_generateQI` shortcut properly, as in `XPCOMUtils.generateQI.bind(XPCOMUtils)`. Otherwise, if the implementation changes and requires a proper `this`, your stuff will break.
5. To export something from any CommonJS module, you need to put it into the `exports` module. See the first link.
6. To import something, use `require()` (first link again).
7. Be aware of circular references, where Module A imports Module B imports Module A. Right now this kinda works (but only kinda, because some stuff might not be available from Module A when Module B imports it like this, as Module A is not fully loaded). Better avoid it.

#### Example 1 (circular)

So here is a example with circular `require` (`main` imports `modules` imports `main`)

`main.js`

```
function someFunction() {
  console.log("some function called");
}

exports.someFunction = someFunction;

var mod = require("./module");
mod.anotherFunction();
```

`module.js`

```
const { someFunction } = require("./main");

exports.anotherFunction = function() {
  someFunction();
}
```

Now, because of circular references this is a *fragile* construct. If works right now, but when modules get more complex or the SDK changes, it might break... Better put `someFunction` into a third module.

#### Example 2 (avoiding circular imports)

`main.js`

```
var mod = require("./module");
mod.anotherFunction();

// Or call someFunction directly
var { someFunction } = require("./utils");
someFunction();
```

`module.js`

```
const { someFunction } = require("./utils");

exports.anotherFunction = function() {
  someFunction();
}
```

`utils.js`

```
function someFunction() {
  console.log("some function called");
}

exports.someFunction = someFunction;
```

There are no circles anymore. If you wanted to reuse `xpcom_generateQI`, you'd put it as a property of `exports` in `utils.js` (in this example) and later require it with `require("./utils")`.

#### https-everywhere

The https-everywhere stuff needs to be either converted or loaded using the subscript loader. I would recommend against the subscript loader, because in all likelihood the verbatim https-everywhere code does not clean up after itself. I'd actually also recommend against just converting it by throwing some stuff in (`exports.xzy = ...`). This code is not meant to be run in the SDK. Better create your own implementation and just borrow ideas from https-everywhere where needed.

Comment: thanks! I guess I really shouldve been able to find the Module structure guide myself..